# user and password authentication asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The user and password are correct but are returning as incorrect. What can it be?

Importantly, the password and encrypted in md5.

```
public static bool logarUsuario(string user, string pw)
    {
        try
        {
            const string checkUser = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbUsuario WHERE userName = '@user'";

            SqlConnection con = Banco.con();

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkUser, con);

            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
            con.Close();

            if (temp == 1)
            {

                con.Open();
                string checkPw = "SELECT pw FROM tbUsuario WHERE userName = '@user'";
                SqlCommand passConn = new SqlCommand(checkPw, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);

                string password = passConn.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                Registrar criptografia = new Registrar();

                if (password == pw)
                {

                    return true;
                }                    
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro " + ex.Message);                
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Within the `btnLogar` click event:

Already checked the database and the username and password are correct, but this as incorrect password.

```
 protected void bntLogar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Registrar criptografia = new Registrar();

        if (Login.logarUsuario(txtUser.Text, criptografia.CriptografiaMD5(txtSenha.Text)))
        {
            //Cria um cookie do lado do servidor
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("estado", "conectado");

            //Define a validade do cookie (10 dias a partir de hoje)
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12);

            //Envia o cookie para o cliente
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

            //Redireciona para a pagina inicial
            Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblErro.Text = "Usuário ou Senha Incorretos";
            lblErro.Visible = true;
            lblErro.CssClass = "alert alert-danger";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Side note: tags on the post say ASP.net but sample uses `Console.WriteLine` - one or another is wrong. Also consider debugging and then editing the post to add information how code fails/mismatches your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single SELECT statement

```
public static bool logarUsuario(string user, string pw)
{
 const string checkUser = 
   @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbUsuario 
      WHERE userName = @u AND pw = @p";

 using (SqlConnection con = Banco.con())
 {
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkUser, con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", user);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", pw);

   return 1 == (int) cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
}
```

This assumes that `pw` is already hashed.

Answer (score 2):

`'@user'` is incorrect.  Do not surround a parameter name with a single quote.  It should look like

```
SELECT pw FROM tbUsuario WHERE userName = @user
```

Also MD5 is no longer considered secure, I suggest using SHA-256.